# Assigning dynamically allocated array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-allocation

Having a lot of trouble with this after sifting through many posts on here. Everything compiles but I get a crash right here during this function which should be dynamically allocating the addresses of one array into this array of pointers. I see one or two memory addresses posted so I'm not sure why it would be crashing during the middle of this.

```
string *copyArray(string ptrArray[],int sizeArray)
   {
    string **dynamString = new string*[sizeArray];
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<=sizeArray;++i)
        {
         (*dynamString[i]) = ptrArray[i];
         cout << dynamString[i];
        }
    return *dynamString;

}
```

from main I have:

```
string *arrPtr;
```

and the function call

```
arrPtr = copyArray(arrayOfStrings, arraySize);
```

Comment: Please consider using a vector.

Comment: Why not use `vector<string>` ? Don't manage memory yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<=sizeArray;++i)
```

accesses an element behind the array yielding an ***undefined behavior***. Elements are indexed from `0` to `sizeArray - 1`. Another problem is that you allocate the array of pointers:

```
string **dynamString = new string*[sizeArray];
```

and then you are derefencing these pointers although they do not point to any object yet:

```
(*dynamString[i]) = ptrArray[i];
```

which also causes an *undefined behavior*. In case you wanted to create a deep copy, you should allocate the memory for every object as well:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeArray; ++i)
{
    dynamString[i] = new std::string(ptrArray[i]);
    cout << *dynamString[i];
}
```

However you should avoid using C-style arrays always when it is possible and prefer STL containers instead. In this case it could be neat `std::vector<std::string>` and its constructor that would do the same than your function (just in safer and more reasonable manner with no possible memory leaks):

```
std::vector<std::string> myStrings(arrayOfStrings, arrayOfStrings + arraySize);
```

Comment: ok I see what you are saying and I fixed that, unfortunately it still crashes after 2 out of 27.

Answer (score 1):

ok I fixed it here. My pointer syntax was incorrect.  Here is the correct syntax.

```
dynamString[i] = &ptrArray[i];
```